# How to get last part from a URL string in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

How can I read last part (after slash) of url if my url is like this:

```
http://testWeb.com/eng/pay-online/#__hc-action-complete--9d79883508
```

I've tried with $_GET and $_POST but these are empty. Also I've tried using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but it also return url till "pay-online". The project is in wordpress (in case there is something in WP which can solve this).

Comment: you could get the whole url and then split the string based on a regular expression

Comment: The `fragment` (bit after the `#`) doesn't get sent to the server.

Comment: @JonStirling in that case how can we get this last part?

Comment: `get this last part?` you have to manipulate the uri to send the `#` ancor-part as real paramter with javascript. like `http://testWeb.com/eng/pay-online/?ancor=__hc-action-complete--9d79883508`

Comment: I suppose you could do it with JavaScript.

Comment: You want `#__hc-action-complete--9d79883508` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the fragment using JS like:

`var fragment = location.hash.substring(1); // minus the hash`